# Шаблоны JS в Visual Studio Community

Tags: javascript, html5

После установки VS 2015 Community в *Проект->Создать новый* нет шаблонов для Javascript. Есть сам язык, но из всех шаблонов есть только Cordova. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить поддержку Javascript и HTML5 в VS2015 Community.

Answer (score 1):

В Visual Studio шаблоны сгуппированы по серверному языку, а не по языку клиентской части. Выберите

Visual C# / ASP.NET Web Application / ASP.NET 4.6 - Empty

Получите пустой сайт. И дальше уже через Add / New Item добавляйте в него контент.

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем согласен. В версии VS Professional есть язык Javascript с кучей шаблонов проектов (AngularJS, Node.JS) и т.д.

Comment: @Daniel у меня в Ent версии нет. ну Или по крайней мере нет по умолчанию. Посмотрите в ветке Online а не Installed - вдруг их для Community Edition тоже можно скачивать.